# django different sessions on different tabs (unknown amount of different sessions)

Tags: django, session, django-socialauth, django-sessions

I'm trying to create a django app where the same user can open two tabs on the same browser and login as two different sessions, preferably still using cookies.

Some background: my app is a service for other websites, where users are referred to my site from the clients site. so the users enter my domain, but since they come from different sites their accounts must not mix.

Note: if it helps I can redirect the users to a unique URL per client site.

How should I approach this problem? are there any ready solutions for that?

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure whether this can be achieved at all, as sessions might be stored within a cookie and it depends on your browser which cookie it's presenting

Comment: you can do that if you serve them in different third-level domains e.g. `subdomain1.mydomain.com` and `subdomain2.mydomain.com`

Comment: @mastazi that's one of the general directions I was considering, what I don't like about it is the need to create dns records for every client using my service (eg if "somesite.com" is using my service I will have to create a record for somesite.mydomain.com and accept it on my server). is there a way to fake this behavior without actually using different domains? any tricks you may know? thanks

Comment: There are many ways to do this depending on your time and the user workflow you need. A simple way (without creating new dns entries and keep using django-sessions) could be asking the user to relogin when the link contains a different "from" site. For example, using parameters (`mydomain.com/?from=site1`), or rest information (`mydomain.com/site1/`). Note this WONT keep different sessions on differents tabs.

Comment: @AdolAurion thanks, but the problem is not with asking user when to login, the problem is that django session is cookie based, and it use only one cookie (named "sessionid") to store current session. so re-login in tab 2 will also affect the logged-in session on tab 1.

Comment: @Ness if you want to implement that workflow, then you should implement your own session management system and ignore django-sessions. Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862888/different-sessions-for-admin-and-applications-in-django

Comment: The easiest solution to this problem is to use two separate browsers, although that may not be an option here. I often have two or three different browsers open to test different user states: not logged in, logged in, admin.

Comment: @Ness I support the solution proposed by AdolAurion, considering what you said you should probably create your own session. I know it's more work (and probably some external libraries might not work) but it's the most flexible solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using the solution from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862888/different-sessions-for-admin-and-applications-in-django) that [AdolAurion](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3227836/adolaurion) linked in comments. note: my session is a bit different than the solution there:

```
import time
from importlib import import_module

from django.conf import settings
from django.utils.cache import patch_vary_headers
from django.utils.http import cookie_date


class SessionMiddleware(object):
    '''
    session middleware that support multiple sessions based on url
    '''

    def __init__(self):
        engine = import_module(settings.SESSION_ENGINE)
        self.SessionStore = engine.SessionStore

    def get_cookie_name(self, request):
        '''
        get session cookie name based on url
        '''
        return "sessionid_" + request.path.split("/")[1]

    def process_request(self, request):
        session_key = request.COOKIES.get(self.get_cookie_name(request), None)
        request.session = self.SessionStore(session_key)

    def process_response(self, request, response):
        """
        If request.session was modified, or if the configuration is to save the
        session every time, save the changes and set a session cookie or delete
        the session cookie if the session has been emptied.
        """
        try:
            accessed = request.session.accessed
            modified = request.session.modified
            empty = request.session.is_empty()
        except AttributeError:
            pass
        else:
            # First check if we need to delete this cookie.
            # The session should be deleted only if the session is entirely empty
            if self.get_cookie_name(request) in request.COOKIES and empty:
                response.delete_cookie(self.get_cookie_name(request),
                    domain=settings.SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN)
            else:
                if accessed:
                    patch_vary_headers(response, ('Cookie',))
                if modified or settings.SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST:
                    if request.session.get_expire_at_browser_close():
                        max_age = None
                        expires = None
                    else:
                        max_age = request.session.get_expiry_age()
                        expires_time = time.time() + max_age
                        expires = cookie_date(expires_time)
                    # Save the session data and refresh the client cookie.
                    # Skip session save for 500 responses, refs #3881.
                    if response.status_code != 500:
                        request.session.save()
                        response.set_cookie(self.get_cookie_name(request),
                                request.session.session_key, max_age=max_age,
                                expires=expires, domain=settings.SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN,
                                path=settings.SESSION_COOKIE_PATH,
                                secure=settings.SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE or None,
                                httponly=settings.SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY or None)
        return response
```