# Django multiple sites : Prevent cross-site authentification

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-authentication

I'm currently developing 2 different sites at the same time: one of them is a heavily customized django-admin interface, and the other a "stand-alone" website that will share it's database with the previous one .

Even though they are related, I'd like my users not to loosely identify between the two sites : they are both able to be independant of the other.

However, a problem arises when someone is logged in the "admin" site : when they go to the other website, they are automatically logged. Won't happen the other way unless I allow it though, as the admin site requires special permissions in the User model.

I already created an UserProfile that can differentiate an user of one of the sites or of the both.

So, knowing all this, how can I make sure that the customers of the admin site don't get to be authenticated when in the other web site (without, of course, logging them out from the first one) ?

Thanks !

**EDIT :** To format it better, here is what I got , summed up :

- One admin application / site                                                                                   Both running
- One related application / site                                                                                    on same server, 
                                                                                        sharing settings and urls.py

If some is logged in **admin**, I want to require them to create a new session to log on **[related site]** : this, without logging them off the admin site.

What changes should I do to this configuration to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

Put different `SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN` and `SESSION_COOKIE_NAME` for each appication. Hope this solve your issue.

```
SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = 'site1.com' #site2.com for other
SESSION_COOKIE_NAME = 'sid1' #sid2 for other
```

Comment: So, from what I understand, running the two sites on different manage.pys with another settings.py for the second site is mandatory ?

Comment: Nop.you can do this by `SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN=None`.

Comment: I don't understand: from what you're saying, I may or may not need to have multiple settings.py? I edited my question for more clarity about my configuration

Comment: You dont need multiple settings.py if `SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN=None` to avoid session sharing(its default).For session sharing you need to`SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN='.domain.com'`

Comment: Well tried that but didn't work, i'm currently using [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862888/different-sessions-for-admin-and-applications-in-django) I found afterwards, and it works well (for now, that is.) Thanks though for trying to help me !